# Mercurial merge - auto merging certain conflict patterns

Tags: mercurial, merge, pom.xml

We merge Maven pom.xml files from one repository to another.

The pom.xml files list a version in this form:

```
<version>5.0.17-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Where we have a conflict on this line we always want to use the local file's version of the conflict.  Is there a way to automatically take the local file version of the change?

For any other conflicts, we would like to continue to use the standard manual merge process.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  Check out the [Merge Tool Configuration](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration) wiki page and you'll see that something like this should do it:

```
 [merge-patterns]
 pom.xml = internal:local
```

Comment: Right.  But that would work on the entire pom.xml file.  We just want to apply that to the one type of conflict in pom.xml files - `<version>x.x.x</version>`

Comment: Ah, I read "for any other conflicts" as "for any other files that conflict"

Comment: You could easily write a merge-pom.sh script with logic like: if the **only** conflicts are `<version>` lines then use internal:local, else launch the manual merge tool.  That would save you from seeing the merge tool in the common case when the only changes were version.  With some more work you could have your script go through and "pick local" line by line whenever the line is a `<version>` and **then** launch the merger on the already partially merged line, but you're probably hitting diminishing returns with that level of complexity.

Comment: I like the idea of the script to use internal:local where the only conflicts are <version>.  Do you have any sample code to do that?  Or a link to docs that would help us write such a script?

Comment: Is there a way to find out how to call another built-in merge tool, or the default tool, from a custom script?  I'm not sure where they'd be found.  Or is it possible to use `hg merge` or `resolve` itself within the script to do so.  It also seems like it could be simpler to just modify the source code of, say, merge3, to behave differently on a match.